# script failing with "chmod: ... Operation not permitted"

Tags: permissions, chmod

A script of mine works fine when I run it, but fails when run by a different user, with an error of the form

```
chmod: changing permissions of `/A/B/C/D/E': Operation not permitted
```

(Here `/A/B/C/D/E` is a directory.  FWIW, the script resides in `/A/B/C/D`.)

In case it matters, the permissions structure of the directory in question and all its ancestors is as follows:

```
drwxrwsrwx kjo11 proj1 /A/B/C/D/E/
drwxrwsrwx cwr8  proj1 /A/B/C/D/
drwxrwsr-x root  proj1 /A/B/C/
drwxrwsr-x root  proj1 /A/B/
drwxr-xr-x root  root  /A/
drwxr-sr-x root  root  /
```

(In this listing, `kjo11` is my `$USER` name.  As it happens, `cwr8` is the `$USER` name of the user for which the script fails.  In any case, we are both in the `proj1` group.)

The output of `uname` is `Linux`.

I'm stumped.  The only detail that catches my attention is that the error is `Operation not permitted`, as opposed to `Permission denied`, but I can't make anything more out of this.

What conditions can cause such errors on running `chmod`?

Comment: What is the `chmod` command the script is trying to run?  I.e. what is it attempting to change the permissions to?

Comment: @depquid: basically the script always runs something like `mkdir -p blah && chmod 775 blah`, to ensure that directory `blah` exists and has the right permissions...

Comment: @kjo Aha! You can use the `umask` utility to ensure the directory is created with appropriate permissions.

Comment: @D_Bye: that's great advice.  Please add it to your answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Only the owner of a file, or the superuser, may alter the permissions on a file. This is true, even if the user is a member of the group that owns the file and the permissions of the file and parent directory would suggest setting permissions should be possible.

You can control the permissions of files and directories at creation time, by using the `umask` facility of your shell:

```
$ umask 002
$ mkdir -p targetdir
$ ls -ld targetdir
...
drwxrwxr-x  2 dan   wheel    2 19 Mar 15:13 targetdir
```

If you're doing this in a script, it's probably a good idea to save the original umask value so you can restore it upon successful creation of your directories.